# Confused by nature of JS SDK Facebook Events

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a bit of trouble designing the user login/logout mechanism of my website that works with facebook.

The behavior of certain facebook events seems counter-intuitive:

'auth.login' fires on every page load when the user is logged in.

FB.getLoginStatus() fires on every page load, as I would expect

'auth.logout' fires only when the user actually logs out, and unlike 'auth.login,' auth.logout does not fire on every page load when the user is not logged in.

I want to build a system that detects whether or not the users session thinks that user is logged into facebook. If the user's session is set to believe they're logged into facebook, but they're actually not then perform an ajax call to the server and update the session. If the session and the facebook js sdk are in agreement over whether the user is logged in or not, do nothing. And if the user's session is unaware that user is logged into facebook but the js sdk says they are, update the server with an ajax call.

I want to create an application that syncs with the users current facebook login status. And I would like that application to login/logout (by executing an ajax call to my server to update their session) whenever they're facebook status changes. This is difficult since I can't seemto reliably detect when a user logs in or out of facebook.

One particular problem I have is when the user loads the page and they're logged into facebook, BOTH the auth.login event and the FB.getLoginStatus() events fire.

My ultimate question is, what combination of facebook-events or general strategy do i have to use to create such an application. A good example of what I'm going for is hulu.com's implementation of facebook login into their website. Thanks for reading this!

```
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '<?=$facebook_app_id?>', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: false,
             xfbml: true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        console.log('getLoginStatus');
        console.log(response);

        if(response.session){
            if(window.module.Globals.prototype.oauth_uid != response.session.uid){
                //authenticated user unknown to server, update server and set session
                window.module.VCAuth.prototype.session_login();
            }
        }else{
            if(window.module.Globals.prototype.oauth_uid){
                //unauthenticated user with authenticated session, update server and unset session
                window.module.VCAuth.prototype.session_logout();
            }
        }

    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
        console.log('auth.login');
        console.log(response);

    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response){
        console.log('auth.logout');
        console.log('response');
    });

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: are able to do what you set out to do.Even I am trying something similar, and I am unable to correctly logout a user, and keep him logged out. Automatically he is getting logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the same callback for all methods. This way you get one authentication code path to worry about. Like this: (which is not that far off from the code you provided)

```
function authCallback(response) {
    if(response && response.session){
        if(window.module.Globals.prototype.oauth_uid != response.session.uid){
            //authenticated user with invalid session
            window.module.VCAuth.prototype.session_login();
        }
    }else{
        if(window.module.Globals.prototype.oauth_uid){
            //unauthenticated user with authenticated session
            window.module.VCAuth.prototype.session_logout();
        }
    }
}

FB.getLoginStatus( authCallback );
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', authCallback);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', authCallback);
```

You said one main problem was:

> BOTH the auth.login event and the FB.getLoginStatus() events fire.

Just make sure that session_logout() and session_login() set/unset the oauth_uid before making the async call to the server so that the next time the callback is called the correct state of the VCAuth is set.

**Note:** auth.logout is not fired every page load because auth.logout implies the user was logged in. It doesn't make sense to fire auth.logout if the user was never logged in right?

Hope this helps.